# ODBC varchar(max) parameter seems to throw "HY104 - Invalid precision value" for 8000 characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I have a stored procedure with an input parameter of `varchar(max)` and we're inserting this parameter into a table column of type `varchar(max)` (e.g. the length is set to -1).
I'm using ODBC because we're configured to use DSN (it's a legacy app).

My `OdbcParameter` is specified as being `OdbcType.VarChar`.

It's called with `ExecuteNonQuery` and when the data is exactly 8000 characters it throws the following exception:

> InnerException: Message: ERROR [HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value
>   StackTrace:    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter.Bind(OdbcStatementHandle hstmt, OdbcCommand command, Int16 ordinal, CNativeBuffer parameterBuffer, Boolean allowReentrance)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameterCollection.Bind(OdbcCommand command, CMDWrapper cmdWrapper, CNativeBuffer parameterBuffer)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
>      at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I am unable to recreate this locally (the error is happening in our production system, so I'm unable to run manual tests there).

While investigating the code I noticed that when we create the OdbcParameter, we're not setting the `Size` parameter.

I'm trying to work out how to stop the errors. So far my ideas are:

1. Specify the size when we create the `OdbcParameter`;
2. If the length is exactly 8000, append a space to the end (it's XML so when it's read back out it will be parsed into a `XDocument` so I thing an appended space won't make any difference);
3. Maybe try and use a `SqlConnection` instead of an `OdbcConnection` and see if the problem goes away.

But because I can't recreate the error, this is all a stab in the dark.
What could be the actual reason for the error, and what would be the best way of fixing it? I know there's some sort of change of datapage or something for varchar over 8000 in length but I can't find anything concrete that's related to ODBC.

Comment: I suspect this is a legacy bug of some sort with ODBC. The max length you can specify for `varchar` in SQL Server is 8000 apart from `max` which was introduced later on (I want to say SQL2008 but I can't remember) to replace use of the `text` type.

Comment: @DavidG it works fine for varchar parameter sizes above and below 8000 - it appears to be only occurring when the data is precisely 8000 in length. I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suspect an ODBC bug, I've not used that for a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

The `SQL Server` ODBC driver that ships with Windows hasn't been updated for the new features introduced after SQL 2000 and is only intended to be used when backwards compatibility is required with legacy applications developed for the pre-SQL 2005 world.

Try using a modern ODBC driver, like [`ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567), which directly supports the `varchar(MAX)` data type introduced in SQL 2005.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll look into this, but it's annoying that I can't recreate it using the 6.03.9600.17415 driver even though it's the same on our dev server as it is on our PROD server.

Comment: @MattJones, I can't say why the behavior would be different in dev versus prod. Are the .NET versions the same? That said, one should use `SqlClient` for SQL Server data access in .NET unless there are other considerations. That will perform much better than ODBC with large result sets too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything is the same! .NET versions, driver versions... A move to `SqlClient` is in the works, but because this uses legacy code I don't know if that's feasible for right now.

Comment: @MattJones, I agree not being able to repro is annoying. One more thing to check is the SQL Server version and patch level. Maybe different server-side API procs (e.g. `sp_prepare`) explains the different behavior.

Comment: I managed to reproduce finally on a server in a pre-production environment, and was able to fix the issue by specifying the size when binding the parameter. But def going to look at updating to SqlClient asap!

Answer (score 0):

Although I still haven't determined the exact cause, I found that setting the `Size` field on the `OdbcParameter` to the actual size of the data appears to fix the issue.

Tested with values of exactly 8000 and below and above that too, just to verify.