# Inject a dataframe into SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio

My problem is related to injecting a DataFrame into SQL using SQLAlchemy and pyodbc. My script works fine in my old script converted to an executable, but when I run the same script in Visual Studio Code,

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import urllib
    import pyodbc
    
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=vmalsdisdb;DATABASE=Produits")
            
            engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

Leo.to_sql('PRELEVEMENT_CANAL_DIRECT', con=engine, schema='dbo', method='multi', chunksize=200, index=False,if_exists='append')
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

pyodbc.Error: ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
   
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context self.dialect.do_execute( File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters) pyodbc.Error: ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Valeur de précision non valide (0) (SQLBindParameter)')The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1948, in call return self.func(*args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "c:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\Test universel2.py", line 450, in inject Leo.to_sql('PRELEVEMENT_CANAL_DIRECT', con=engine, schema='dbo', method='multi', chunksize=200, index=False,if_exists='append') File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 333, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3081, in to_sql return sql.to_sql( ^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 842, in to_sql return pandas_sql.to_sql( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2011, in to_sql table = self.prep_table( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1915, in prep_table table.create() File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 984, in create if self.exists(): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 970, in exists return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2044, in has_table return insp.has_table(name, schema or self.meta.schema) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 429, in has_table return self.dialect.has_table( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 2892, in wrap return _switch_db( ^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 2916, in _switch_db return fn(*arg, **kw) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 3305, in has_table return self._internal_has_table(connection, tablename, owner, **kw) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "", line 2, in _internal_has_table File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 97, in cache ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 3408, in _internal_has_table c = connection.execute(s) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in execute return meth( ^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 517, in _execute_on_connection return connection._execute_clauseelement( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement ret = self._execute_context( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context return self._exec_single_context( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context self._handle_dbapi_exception( File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2344, in _handle_dbapi_exception raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context self.dialect.do_execute( File "C:\Users\HAMZAM\Desktop\projet python\pythonProject1\testprojet\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Valeur de précision non valide (0) (SQLBindParameter)') [SQL: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEM A].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))] [parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'PRELEVEMENT_CANAL_DIRECT', 'dbo')] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

Note that I have checked the data types of the DataFrame and the table, and everything is okay

Comment: is there qa good cause, why you didn't post the code that produces the error

Comment: Please provide the code causing the exception. It's impossible to say without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: "Injection" is a loaded term when talking about SQL. Do you want to *import* the contents of the dataframe into a SQL database?

Comment: @chepner: Yes, I want to inject a DataFrame into an SQL table. I've already managed to do it, and my script works in the executable version, but when I run the script in Visual Studio code, it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I did find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255314/odbc-varcharmax-parameter-seems-to-throw-hy104-invalid-precision-value-for) which says it may have to do with the driver version you're using... /shrug

Comment: Is the packaged executable 64 bit, or 32 bit? Because some drivers are only available in one environment not the other. Instead of using `DRIVER={SQL Server};` which in most cases would select `SQL Server Native Client 11` but inside your VS Code seems to be selecting an old `ODBC SQL Server Driver` (maybe 11 or 13), have you tried specifying a modern driver to use like `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` or  `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};`? (Depends on what you have installed.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Having installed the ODBC SQL Server 17 driver, the issue seems resolved. Now, I'm wondering about the need to install this driver on every PC where I want to run my script as an executable.